# Collation with union and tempdb

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

I have temporary table in tempdb, and a table in database. When I construct query with union of this 2 table. There is an error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Cyrillic_General_CI_AI"
> and "Cyrillic_General_CI_AS" in the UNION operation.

```
drop table [sysdb].[##temp table];
create table [sysdb].[##temp table](a varchar);
insert into [sysdb].[##temp table] (a) values ('a'),('b');


select grade_name from [mybase].[DDS].[testtable]
union
select * from [sysdb].[##temp table];
```

I have tested my collation parametrs in databases with this query:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('mybase', 'Collation') as collation_dwh,DATABASEPROPERTYEX('tempdb', 'Collation') as collation_tempdb
```

Result is that the collation of databases is the same:

> collation_dwh                   |         collation_tempdb
>
> Cyrillic_General_CI_AI    |   Cyrillic_General_CI_AI

How to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you explicitly set the collation in the `union` it should be fine:

```
select grade_name collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AI from [mybase].[DDS].[testtable]
union
select a collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AI from [sysdb].[##temp table];
```

Note that columns can have a collation different from the database.

Answer (score 1):

**Collation In Sql Server:**

> Collation  is set of rules that determine how data is sorted and
>   compared. Currently sql has four level of collation
>   (***Server,Database,Table & Column***).

**Reason For Collation Conflict:**

> You faced mismatches in levels of collation between the the tables.

**Fixes:**

> As per the Microsoft changing the server level collation is not a easy
>   fix. [Source:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
>   Before that you need to address all non default collation on columns for all
>   tables in SQL Server

```
DECLARE @DatabaseCollation VARCHAR(100)

SELECT 
    @DatabaseCollation = collation_name 
FROM 
    sys.databases
WHERE 
    database_id = DB_ID()

SELECT 
    @DatabaseCollation 'Default database collation'

SELECT 
    t.Name 'Table Name',
    c.name 'Col Name',
    ty.name 'Type Name',
    c.max_length,
    c.collation_name,
    c.is_nullable
FROM 
    sys.columns c 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id    
WHERE 
    t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND 
    c.collation_name <> @DatabaseCollation
```

- [Re-Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx) SQL Server one of the best solution.

> For temporary fix use below query.

```
SELECT grade_name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT from [mybase].[DDS].[testtable]
UNION
SELECT a COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT from [sysdb].[##temp table];
```